# Bypass max array size in no arg constructor

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, constructor

I am trying to remove the limit, through the default setting, when adding new numbers. I wish to still have a limit on the all-arg constructor, that is set when initialized, but not on the no-arg and 1-arg constructors.

```
public class SMSDataModelList implements SMSDataModelInterface, Serializable {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_PHONE_NUMBERS = 20;

    public static final String FULL = "FULL";
    public static final String DUPLICATE = "DUPLICATE";

    private String message;     //The SMS message
    private String[] phoneNumbers;      //The collection of phone numbers
    private int maxNumPhoneNumbers;     //Max numbers in list

    public SMSDataModelList(String message) {
        this(message, DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_PHONE_NUMBERS);
    }   

    public SMSDataModelList() {
        this("", DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_PHONE_NUMBERS);
    }

    public SMSDataModelList(String initialMessage, int maxNumPhoneNumbers) {
        this.message = initialMessage;
        this.maxNumPhoneNumbers = maxNumPhoneNumbers;
        this.phoneNumbers = new String[maxNumPhoneNumbers];
    }

    @Override
    public String addPhoneNumber(String newPhoneNumber) {
        String result;

        if (list.size() == maxNumPhoneNumbers) {
            result = FULL;

        } else {
            boolean exists;
            exists = findPhoneNumberIndex(newPhoneNumber) != -1;

            if (exists) {
                result = DUPLICATE;
            } else {
                list.add(newPhoneNumber);
                result = newPhoneNumber;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }       
}
```

I have tried adding this to the addPhoneNumber method:

```
if (DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_PHONE_NUMBERS == 20) {
    maxNumPhoneNumbers = (list.size() + 1);
}
```

I thought this was working well with testing the no-arg and 1-arg constructors, but when it came to the all-arg, I noticed it allowed the array size to increase there too. I can see why that was wrong now, but not sure if I was on the right track.

Is it actually possible for me to make the no-arg and 1-arg constructors have unlimited array sizes with a static default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, it seems you require another flag in your constructors, to indicate whether the number of phones should be limited to the initial maximum number:

```
public SMSDataModelList(String message) {
    this(message, DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_PHONE_NUMBERS, false);
}   

public SMSDataModelList() {
    this("", DEFAULT_MAX_NUM_PHONE_NUMBERS, false);
}

public SMSDataModelList(String initialMessage, int maxNumPhoneNumbers) {
    this(initialMessage, maxNumPhoneNumbers, true);
}

public SMSDataModelList(String initialMessage, int maxNumPhoneNumbers, boolean limited) {
    this.message = initialMessage;
    this.maxNumPhoneNumbers = maxNumPhoneNumbers;
    this.phoneNumbers = new String[maxNumPhoneNumbers];
    this.limited = limited;
}
```

You can use the `limited` flag to determine whether the `phoneNumbers` array can be increased when it becomes full - you'll need to add logic to `addPhoneNumber` that checks that flag.

P.S. I just noticed that your constructors and instance variables don't match the `addPhoneNumber` method. The constructors initialize an array to store the phone numbers while the `addPhoneNumber` method uses an `ArrayList`. You should decide which of the two you wish to use. An `ArrayList` would be easier, since you won't have to re-allocate a new array each time the existing array becomes full.

Comment: This is my first attempt at using an `ArrayList`, I wasn't aware that I was doing something wrong here. I have a similar program that uses just arrays, but I can't seem to translate it to an `ArrayList`

Comment: @azzabloom Where are you storing the phone numbers? In `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()` or in `private String[] phoneNumbers`? You should choose one.

Comment: I fixed it, it's now `List<String> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>()` and  I deleted the array refernce. In the all-arg constructor I changed it to `this.phoneNumbers = new ArrayList(maxNumPhoneNumbers);` and everything works fine. I still do not understand how to remove the maxNumPhoneNumbers limit on the 0-arg and 1-arg constructors though.

Comment: Used a flag as suggested and got it work, thank you!